# Oracle: transform wm_concat in an Analytic Function

Tags: oracle

I was reading that it should be really simple to use an Aggregate function as an Analytic Function [link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14289/dciaggfns.htm). I would like to use wm_concat in Oracle 10g as an analytic function.

Comment: Have you looked at example 11.9? What is your problem with implementing this?

Answer (score 0):

It simply works as suggested!!! Really good thanks!

```
WITH temp as (
SELECT 'A' as master , 1 Col from dual
UNION SELECT 'A' , 3  from dual
UNION SELECT 'B' , 1 from dual
UNION SELECT 'B' , 2 from dual
UNION SELECT 'C' , 1 from dual)
SELECT
   master,
   wm_concat(Col) over (partition by master)
FROM
  temp
```